# Formatting date in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-dates

How can I easily format "202104" --> 2021/04 in Excel?

My current method is to concatenate the original string with "01" and then change it into a date. However, I am seeking a more efficient format method.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need it to be an actual date, or just text, or a formatted number? If just formatted, a custom format of 0000"/"00 would do. For text, you can use the `TEXT` function with the same format. For a real date, your current way is as good as any.

Comment: I need it as an actual date. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Then depending on how you "change it to a date", I don't really see what alternative there is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

For Text

```
=LEFT(A1,4)&"/"&RIGHT(A1,2)
```

For Date Value

```
=TEXT(DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,4)&"/"&RIGHT(A1,2)),"YYYY/MM")
```

Comment: Thanks, the Text version works well. However, I get a Value error with the second attempt.

Comment: @qwerty you replied to a comment on your Q _I need it as an actual date_.  These returns a string,  not a date

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, 2021/04 is not a valid date in Excel, but 2021/04/01 (first of April, year 2021) is.

In order to achieve this, you can use this formula:

```
=DATE(INTEGER(202104 / 100);MOD(202104;100);1)
```

Where:

```
1) INTEGER(202104/100) is the integer division of 202104 by 100, calculating the year.
2) MOD(202104;100) means 202104 modulo 100, in order to calculate the month.
3) 1 means the first day of the month.
```